# Kivy run function from kv button

Tags: python, function, class, kivy

I'm new at kivy and try to run a do_login function inside my MyApp Class from a kv generated button.

my kv layout with the button

```
RelativeLayout:
    FloatingActionButton:
        id:                 float_act_btn
        on_press:           ???how to call call do_login from MyApp
```

and my class with the containing do_login function

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_string(login_kv) 

def do_login(self, *args):
    print'jo'
```

How to use on_press to call do_login?

with on_press:do_login(login.text, password.text)' I get 'do_login' is not defined and the same with self.do_login I get MaterialRaisedButton' object has no attribute 'do_login'

Answer (score 17, accepted):

make `do_login` a member of the MyApp class:

```
class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_string(login_kv) 

    def do_login(self, *args):
        print'jo'
```

and use `app` in `kv` as the keyword to access MyApp and call the function:

```
on_press: app.do_login()
```

from [Kivy language](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html):

```
There are three keywords specific to Kv language:

app: always refers to the instance of your application.
root: refers to the base widget/template in the current rule
self: always refer to the current widget
```